# How do I make my CSS 'typewriter' animation from stopping when my it has finished 'typing' out my text, instead of just moving all across my page?

Tags: html, css

all.
I copypasted some code from this website/tutorial: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-create-a-typewriter-text-with-only-css.html

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="typewriter">
        <h1>I am a Website Developer.</h1>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS Code:

```
.typewriter h1 {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';
    letter-spacing: .17em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: .17em solid pink;
    animation: typing 3.5s steps(30, end), blinking-cursor .5s step-end infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes typing {
    from {
      width: 0
    }
    to {
      width: 100%
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes blinking-cursor {
    from,
    to {
      border-color: transparent
    }
    50% {
      border-color: black;
    }
}
```

And something I have been trying to figure out is how to stop the animation from expanding from one of my screen to the other. Anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Great Tutorial: https://youtu.be/4Mxv8KcAdLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to you specifying 100% width on the keyframes. If you play around with that, you'll also have to specify a `width` property on your `h1` tag in order to get the animation to end correctly.

Change this:

```
@keyframes typing {
    from {
      width: 0
    }
    to {
      width: 100%
    }
  }
```

to this:

```
@keyframes typing {
    from {
      width: 0
    }
    to {
      width: 50%
    }
  }
```

and then you can add a 50% width to your `h1` element to allow the typing animation to just finish off instead of finishing and throwing the text to the left and pushing the cursor to the right of the page.

You are going to have to play around with the 50% to get it to be the width of your text, I just went off what the example had and eyed it at roughly 50%. Your text could be different though, so see what you can do with that but it should help.

Comment: Doesn't Work in my case